# How to replace a string in the output of the JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to replace a string inside a JSON object. 
My JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "type":         "text",
    "timeTrigger":  34,
    "title":        "Sherlock Holmes",
    "subtitle":     "Detective",
    "picture":      "images/content/placehold.png",
    "intro":        "Sherlock Holmes is a fictional detective created by British author Sir Arthur Conan Doyle. [gallery] Holmes is known for his astute logical reasoning..."
            },
```

What I would like to replace is the tag `[gallery]` to an image object.

I tried this:

```
var mystring = data.text;
mystring.replace('[gallery]' , 'replaced!');
```

And this:

```
var stringified = JSON.stringify(json);
stringified = stringified.replace('"[gallery]": "replaced"');
```

Both will result in that nothing is changed. The last one, I thought is only to use when you would like to change the key > value in the JSON, but I would only like to filter out the gallery tag and replace it with an image. SO the output will replace `[gallery]` into an image object.

Any advice and code is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The script bellow will replace the data.text that contains `[gallery]` with something new, but this works only in the console.log and not for the same text on the page..

```
var mystring = data.text;
console.log(mystring.replace('[gallery]', '=========dsiuhfodsa========='));
```

Comment: Yes. Yes, that's certainly possible within the realm of reality.

Comment: That isn't a feature of JSON or JavaScript. There are plenty of template languages (with compilers written in JS) which let you express a template in the form of a string and you can store strings in JSON.

Comment: Your question is *actually* "is it possible to replace text in a string" (google "replace in string javascript") and the answer is an obvious yes. Regardless of the source of data, it doesn't change the simplicity of the question.

Comment: Should I first parse my JSON and use then replace() or can I directly use replace?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Your object has no `text` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.replace()` function and using regular expression with these special characters after the second forward slash greedy `g` which matches all occurrence of the term`[gallery]` and `i` case-insensitive, Also don't forget to escape the `[` and `]` with backslashes to match them as well.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ubg426p1/2/)

```js
var div = document.getElementById('intro'),
 data = {
      "type"  : "text",
      "timeTrigger":  34,
      "title"  : "Sherlock Holmes",
      "subtitle" : "Detective",
      "picture" : "images/content/placehold.png",
      "intro"  : "Sherlock Holmes is a fictional detective created by British author Sir Arthur Conan Doyle. [gallery] Holmes is known for his astute logical reasoning..."
            };
var intro = data['intro'];
div.innerHTML = intro.replace(/\[gallery\]/ig, '<img src="//placehold.it/100x100?image">');
```

```html
<div id="intro"></div>
```